# Pressure queries on turbopumps

Tags: liquid-fuel, turbopump, pressure

In the turbopump used in liquid rockets, the stagnation pressure rise is definite. But then the question comes:

1. Whether static pressure rises or dynamic pressure rises or both rise? If both rise which has the most significant increase?
2. On what factors will the increase depend upon? (some numbers will be nice for the domination :))
3. When the inlet and outlet diameter of the pump is same, will there be only static pressure rise?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the pump raises the kinetic head along with pressure head because injector needs a lot of injection speed also, so why not have them ready at the pump instead of converting later? The whole of LPRE is centered around the main combustion chamber hitting a certain pressure, and all of the plumbing, including the pumps, are tailored to hit that goal. The pumps are simple centrifugal designs and work like your normal simple centrifugal pumps. If water is pumped and the outlet line same as the inlet line then sure only static pressure changes, as is often the case during cold flow testing.

Comment: What is "LPRE"?

Comment: @Organic Marble my bad = liquid propellant rocket engine